# I am getting an error "Cant convert from int to System.net.http.httpcompletionoption"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I cant find anything on google for this error and im just wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before. This is my first time building a REST Web API and im connecting it to my MVC application just trying to do a simple GET with a ID to build a details page ill post code below.

```
 public ActionResult Details(Contact contactid)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56194/");
        //CODE BELOW IS TAKING THE CLIENT AND ALLOWS IT TO ACCEPT JSON DATA
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts", contactid.ID).ContinueWith((Posttank) => Posttank.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           contact  = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Contact>().Result;
        }
        return View(contact);

    }
```

And my Web Api method is:

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(contact))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getcontact(int id)
    {
        contact contact = db.contacts.Find(id);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(contact);
    }
```

Thanks guys,

Comment: Where do you get that error? Pointing to the right line of code would help a lot. What the error is saying though is that at some point the code expects an HttpCompletionOption and you are passing it an int instead. From the looks of things its probably your call to client.GetAsync where you seem to be passing a string and an int which isn't a valid overload (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync(v=vs.118).aspx for ways to call it).

Answer (score -2):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts/"+contactid.ID).ContinueWith((Posttank) => Posttank.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
```

Just Try like this..